# PDF mail attachments in IIS

Tags: email, iis, pdf, attachment

I have to send emails with PDF attachments in my application (C#,ASP.NET). That function is working fine in local host, but when i deployed it to the server, attachments are not working. only the email send to the users. Do i need to set any special configuration on windows server 2008 R2 ?

Comment: can you provide any file name you attach?

Comment: ok. finally i found that, its a problem with securing the PDF. Thanks  Volodymyr

Comment: Cool then post your answer :) maybe some one else will have that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a server related issue. I have used Syncfusion to secure the PDF file. when it deploys to the server, we need to create a new PdfCertificate for the server. Otherwise it will not work on the server.